# A_Parity_Error_?

Tags: networking, freebsd, hard-disk, checksum

Now this is odd:  While copying a tarred directory over my LAN using ssh from a Fedora machine to a FreeBSD machine.  I get:  `Uncorrectable parity/CRC error`

(All the disks are set with S.M.A.R.T  – disks on both machines are same user, group, and access permissions `770`. I already tried changing cables and SATA ports. I also ran a quick test with the bootable WD drive software -- it passed)

As this only appears on one of the four disk on the FreeBSD machine, I was getting ready to toss the disk; now I’m less sure.

By chance, while logged on to the FreeBSD machine as root the error message does not appear. This test was verified several times.

(Also, even while logged in as a regular user and getting the error message the copy completes.  I compared file sizes with `ls -l`  – so the copies appear to be fine.)

---

Yes I already ran fsck on it; it's clean
'

Comment: Have you run `fsck` (whatever that may be on BSD)?

Comment: @HaukeLaging fsck originated in 4.0BSD in 1980 so, on FreeBSD, it's fsck.